# Can difflib's charjunk be used to ignore whitespace?

Tags: python, whitespace, difflib

I'd like to compare differences between two lists of strings. For my purposes, whitespace is noise and these differences do not need to be shown.  Reading into [difflib's documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html), "the default [for `charjunk`] is module-level function `IS_CHARACTER_JUNK()`, which filters out whitespace characters". Perfect, except I don't see it working, or making much difference (<- pun!).

```
import difflib
A = ['3  4\n']
B = ['3 4\n']
print ''.join(difflib.ndiff(A, B))  # default: charjunk=difflib.IS_CHARACTER_JUNK
```

outputs:

```
- 3  4
?  -
+ 3 4
```

I've tried a few other `linejunk` options, but none that actually ignore the differences as a result of whitespace. Do I have the wrong interpretation for what `charjunk` is for?

As a side note, I can side-step this limitation by pre-processing my strings to substitute multiple whitespace characters to single space characters using `re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', 'foo\t bar')`.

Comment: Have you succeed?